# Holding companies to cancel out profits?

Tags: taxes

I have two companies:

- Company A is established and makes about 20k in profits
- Company B is lost 8k last year since it's new.

If I were to create a holding company, Company C, and owned both companies through Company C, could the losses from Company B offset the profits from Company A?

A CPA recommended this strategy but it sounds too good to be true. Any advice would help!

Comment: Tax questions need a country tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the U.S., pass-through S-corp companies already net their incomes on the personal tax forms of the company owners.

But C-corps hold their own financial results and only pay salaries and dividends. However, C-corps get the corporate tax rate instead of the personal tax rate. Now, dividends from a C-corp face double taxation.

So if Company A and Company B were S-corp companies they could pass-through their income to Company C, as their owner, and get the corporate income tax rate if Company C were a C-corp. The owners of Company C would most likely only take salaries and not dividends.

This situation of likely only taking salaries from a C-corp is why many professionals prefer pass-through S-corp companies.